# Identity of plant bearing a cluster of bulbous, glossy red fruits (Oak Ridges Moraine)

Tags: species-identification, botany, fruit

- Location: Oak Ridges Moraine, Ontario (Durham Region)
- Date: October 4, 2021
- Site: Full shade; hillside; sugar bush

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't a flower, but the cluster of shiny berries containing the seeds of a flower. My best guess is that it is a [Jack-in-the-Pulpit](https://anps.org/2015/05/15/know-your-natives-jack-in-the-pulpit-green-dragon/) (Arisaema triphyllum), but it's a bit hard to tell from the two leaves, which are both decomposing and at a bad angle to tell for sure. But it's definitely in the Arum family.

[image: Picture of Arisaema triphyllum]

Their range includes Eastern US and Ontario.

Named because the flower resembles a preacher in a covered pulpit, the flowers are tiny, and bloom on the spadix (the "Jack") of a mature female. When young, the flowers are male; when sufficiently mature, they become female and can form the berry cluster.

From the site [linked above](https://anps.org/2015/05/15/know-your-natives-jack-in-the-pulpit-green-dragon/):

> Berries (¼ inch across) enclosing one to several seeds, at first green, become bright red as female plants begin to wither in late summer and fall.  Berries remain attached to the dry spadix, resulting in an ovoid mass of showy berries up to 2 inches long which stay on the stem even when stem has dried.  A cluster can consist of up to 150 berries, each with 1 to 3 rounded flat-sided light tan seeds.